# nested SQL queries on one table

Tags: sql

I am having trouble formulating a query to get the desired output.
This query involves one table and two columns. 
First column `bld_stat` has 4 different values  `Private`, `public`, `Public-Abandoned`, `Private-Abandoned` the other column `bld_type`, `single_flr`, `multi_flr`, `trailer`, `Whs`. 
I need to get results that look like this:

[image: http://gisweb.centuryeng.com/testing/image/table.png]

So far I can get the first two columns but after that I have not been able to logically get a query to work

```
SELECT bld_stat, COUNT(grade) AS single_flr
FROM (SELECT bld_stat,bld_type
      FROM bld_inventory WHERE bld_type = 'single_flr') AS grade
      GROUP BY bld_stat,bld_type,grade
```

Comment: You should consider saving the first SELECT as a view.  Then joing THAT to your second SELECT.  You'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: You are looking for `pivot`

Comment: Don't think a view / subquery is needed

Comment: why on earth would you create a view for this simple query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you are going for is pivoting.  I think this should work...no need for the subquery, and I've changed your group by to only bld_stat

```
SELECT bld_stat, 
sum(case when bld_type = 'singl_flr' then 1 else 0 end) AS single_flr,
sum(case when bld_type = 'multi_flr' then 1 else 0 end) AS multi_flr,
sum(case when bld_type = 'trailer' then 1 else 0 end) AS trailer,
sum(case when bld_type = 'whs' then 1 else 0 end) AS WHS
FROM bld_inventory
 GROUP BY bld_stat
```

Comment: Thanks Twelfth I have never heard or used Pivoting before... I implemented your query above and I received a error  syntax error at or near ")" So I deleted all but the first cast statement and Added a END after else 0 and it worked however I can not get the other case statements to work

Comment: I missed all my commas. editting. Try again...after each case statement, I missed the comma to denote a new field. include comma's error should go away...sloppy coding on my part